# Bottom toolbar layout

Tags: android, layout

I have created two toolbars one top and one bottom.

And the result is like this:

[image]

My question is, how can i make my bottom toolbar's items centered and their widths span vertically to fit the toolbar?

Here is what i've done:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="app.shinobi.org.ssmis.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <app.shinobi.org.util.tab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/stats_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/stats_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

These are my two menus:

for the top toolbar:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="app.shinobi.org.ssmis.MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/search" android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"  android:orderInCategory="1" app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item android:id="@+id/refresh" android:title="@string/action_refressh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh" android:orderInCategory="2" app:showAsAction="always" />
```

for the bottom toolbar:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="app.shinobi.org.ssmis.MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/monthly" android:title="@string/action_monthly"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh" android:orderInCategory="3" app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/yearly" android:title="@string/action_yearly"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh" android:orderInCategory="4" app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/drugs" android:title="@string/action_drugs"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh" android:orderInCategory="5" app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try applying the gravity of the  stats_toolbar to center?

Comment: You app has a cool design!

Comment: @V.Kalyuzhnyu, seriously? Thanks though.

Comment: Red color - my favourite. And it looks very good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a menu will always put your button to the end of the toolbar.
If you want to center these buttons, you will have to use `toolbar.addView(view)` where your view can inflate from a xml file like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you just have to:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setContentInsetsRelative(0, 0);
        toolbar.addView(
                LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.toolbar, null, false),
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        );
```

Comment: ill try this, so how can I handle events from here?

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer :3 But can you please ,add on how to handle events. Though, i already solved it maybe others might be needing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest one not very good solution but it works. If i right understand in include layout you have a toolbar view. Its a container so you can use it like relative or linear layout. And put buttons or other views inside it. And write properties like gravity in center. That is all.

Another way - do smth with items in menu layout may be. But i don't know how(

PS: a short example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="previousActivity"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_white_24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact us"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: can you reference me some links or whatever... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use a `ActionMenuView` to replace your bottom Toolbar

Or you can try this SplitToolbar implementation

https://gist.github.com/dodgex/7bc81fd2cbb70a8d5117

Comment: i'll search about ActionMenuView, and get back to you later.

Comment: actually this behaves slightly different from what you described, it evenly split the space in between the menu items. If you really need to have equal spaces buttons, you may simply use LinearLayout, however you cannot use the menu structure. Or you have to implements or override ActionMenuView (which is actually just a LinearLayout)